# На python исправить некорректный xml

Tags: python, xml

Допустим, есть файл xml с некорректной структурой (незакрытые теги, теги без одной угловой скобки и так далее). Как на python его исправить?

Comment: что значит исправить -- проигнорировать ошибки, использовать *всезнание* и догадаться каким входной файл должен быть? Например, если тег не закрыт, то как узнать где автор документа хотел закрыть этот тег, чтобы превратить файл в корректный xml?

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

Формат XML, в отличие от HTML, является строгим и не допускает никаких ошибок. Парсер, соответствующий стандартам, должен останавливать обработку при первой встреченной ошибке и не пытаться ничего исправить.

Парсер XML, поставляемый с Python, этим требованиям соответствует, поэтому не включает обработку ошибок.

Браузеры, если потребовать от них обработку страницы как XHTML (как HTML, только в строгом соответствии XML), при нахождении ошибки в тексте могут попытаться обработать XHTML как HTML. Можете пойти тем же путём, например, воспользоваться [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

"Исправление" ошибок при чтении XML **крайне не рекомендуется**. Оно уже привело ко всевозможным проблемам для HTML, в результате пришлось в новый стандарт включать уйму маловменяемой логики, чтобы хоть как-то привести браузеры к общему знаменателю. В случае XML авторы стандарта поступили проще и правильнее: если в файле XML ошибка, то это проблема того, кто этот файл сгенерировал, а не того, кто этот файл пытается прочитать.